# Can't create file as another user

Tags: permissions, mongodb

This may be related to MongoDB, but I'm not really sure.

While trying to run MongoDB on a mounted disk I found that its user (`mongodb`) has no permissions to the folder it's configured to (`/media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb`).

I then tried running:

```
sudo -H -u mongodb bash -c 'touch /media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb/asd'
```

And got:

```
touch: cannot touch '/media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb/asd': Permission denied
```

When trying with a different user (root, or my own) I was able to touch that file.

I tried (recursively) allowing all possible permissions, currently it looks like this:

```
❯ ll /media/dutzi/hdd/
total 20K
drwxrwxrwx 2 root    root     16K Nov  7 17:25 lost+found/
drwsrwsrwx 4 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:38 mongodb/

dutzi in dutzipc in ~
❯ ll /media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb/
total 204K
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb   47 Nov  7 17:29 WiredTiger*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb   21 Nov  7 17:29 WiredTiger.lock*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 1.3K Nov  7 17:29 WiredTiger.turtle*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  44K Nov  7 17:29 WiredTiger.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 WiredTigerHS.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 _mdb_catalog.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb    0 Nov  7 17:31 as2d*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb    0 Nov  7 17:38 asd*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 collection-0--7241342955860792272.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 collection-2--7241342955860792272.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 collection-4--7241342955860792272.wt*
drwxrwxrwx 2 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 diagnostic.data/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 index-1--7241342955860792272.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 index-3--7241342955860792272.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 index-5--7241342955860792272.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 index-6--7241342955860792272.wt*
drwxrwxrwx 2 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 journal/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb    0 Nov  7 17:29 mongod.lock*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 sizeStorer.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  114 Nov  7 17:29 storage.bson*

dutzi in dutzipc in ~
❯ sudo -H -u mongodb bash -c 'touch /media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb/asdasd'
touch: cannot touch '/media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb/asdasd': Permission denied
```

Comment: What kind of filesystem is on the external disk?

Comment: SeLinux could cause this issue. Also make sure directories **above** are accessible for this user. Does `ls /media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb/asd` under the user mongodb work?

Comment: @roaima it's ext4

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, no `ls` returns "Permission denied" as well, it's Ubunutu if that makes a difference, but I'll try

Comment: If `ls` doesn't work, one of several of the upper directories is inaccessible. Which one - it's you to figure out.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov works! `/media` is root, `/media/dutzi` is dutzi's, `/media/dutzi/hdd` is mongodb's, and so is `/media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb`.

Comment: I guess it's since they have different permissions for other users

Comment: If all the above directories are 775 or 755 you should have no troubles but I guess it's not the case. Check it out.